# border bottom does not show on link

Tags: html, css

I want the underline on hover over a `li` href item to be red. What i did is this:

```
.custom-nav ul{
     list-style:none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}
.custom-nav li {
     display:inline;
     font-size:24px;
     margin:40px;
}
.custom-nav a{
     text-decoration: none;
     width: 50%;
}
.custom-nav a:hover{
     color:rgba(255,228,228,1.00);
     border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-nav">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#">photography</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">digital art</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

So you can see I have tried setting the `a:hover` to have a border bottom but it doesnt seems to work. No underline appears at all! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this i modified just `.custom-nav ul:/*overflow:hidden */`remove this attribute

```css
.custom-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
.custom-nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 40px;
}
.custom-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50%;
}
.custom-nav a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 228, 228, 1.00);
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">photography</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">digital art</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```